# making an activity that opens on a certain day

Tags: java, android, calendar

I've made a radio app for a friend. she has a radio slot on Wednesday evening at 6 pm. I want a certain activity only to open if the app starts during this time slot.

WEEKDAYQUESTION

How could I capture the day of the week?

then using the day of the week could I just write an if statement that said

```
String Weekday = WEEKDAYQUESTION.toString;
if (Weekday.matches("Wednesday"){

}
```

Time Question

How can I capture the current time and then be able to see if it between the times stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main activity, you could check the day of the week and immediately start the new intended activity from the `onCreate` method.

To check the day and time you could use -

```
import java.util.Calendar;

switch (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (hour >= 18 && hour <= 20) {
            Intent intendedActivity = new Intent(this, IntendedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intendedActivity);
        }

}
```

Comment: how could i write the if statement for the time to match the set time frame? so between 6pm and 8pm on a wednesday?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by **AlarmManager**. using the AlarmManager you can set alarm to a particular time with **PendingIntent**. so it will start your activity at a particular time.

More info about AlaramManger:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Tutorial for AlarmManager:

http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/

Comment: sorry i dont want the user to set the alarm them selfs i want it to be automatic as soon as the app opens i want it to capture the time and date and see if it is between 6pm and 8pm on a wednesday if so open activity if not do nothing

Comment: Read the document and tutorial. Your user not going to set an alarm, as you asked you are going to start an activity with the help of AlaramManager class.